# Нужна помощь с задачей. c++

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нужно вывести на экран NO SOLUTION вместо inf
вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){
double c, a, b;
cin >> a >> b;
c = 1/(1 + (a+b)/2);
cout << fixed << setprecision(5) << c;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: лови случай когда a+b == -2 ибо будет деление на 0

Comment: огромное вам спасибо

Comment: IF (a+b == -2) "no solution" ELSE "выводим ответ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверяйте значение `c` и выводите нужную строку

```
#include <math.h>
............
if (isinf(c))
  cout << "NO SULUTION";
else
  cout << fixed << setprecision(5) << c;
```